# pre_dispatch() vs validate()?

Tags: validation

Why use `pre_dispatch()` vs. `validate()`?  What are some guidelines for using `pre_dispatch()`, `post_dispatch()`, and the various variants of `validate()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are for hooking into different parts of the transaction lifecycle. Unlike on_intialize and on_finalize, these run for all transactions.

validate

- used to drop the transaction at the transaction pool and prevents a transaction from being gossiped.

pre-dispatch

- used to hook in before the transaction runs. For example, weight extrinsic uses it to increase the weight count before the transaction.

post-dispatch

- used to hook and do something after the transaction runs. For example, the transaction payment pallet uses it to refund a user of any overpaid fees. The weight extrinsic uses it to update the total amount of weight consumed in a block.

Pre-dispatch also needs to call the validate function. That is because it needs to make sure that the transaction that got processed before it did not cause a modification to the state that would make the transaction invalid.